# Sorting a list<> using command arguments passed from a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, sorting

I have a listview populated using a List<> of objects. I've read on SO how it's possible to sort a list using LINQ like this:

```
List<Order> SortedList = objListOrder.OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate).ToList();
```

Which is fine, but my ListView has a bunch of columns and I want to sort, using a system not dissimilar to the above but to be able to take in the sort value from whatever command argument is passed.

So, for example the above code sorts by OrderDate, what if I passed in 'Name' or 'Amount' or something else. Without having a long if-else is there a nice way for the LINQ query to change depending on the values passed as the sort argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `OrderBy` on a property from a `string` like this:

```
var strSort = "Name";
List<Order> SortedList = objListOrder.OrderBy(o=>o.GetType().GetProperty(strSort).GetValue(o, null)).ToList();
```

I would however prefer to split the query up:

```
var strSort = "Name";

var query = objListOrder;
if(strSort == "OrderDate")
    query = query.OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate);
else if(strSort == "Name")
    query = query.OrderBy(o=>o.Name);
else if(strSort == "Amount")
    query = query.OrderBy(o=>o.Amount);

List<Order> SortedList = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect, this works thanks. I'll mark it as the answer, one thing though, any idea how we'd work in ASC / DESC into the mix, for when they're sorted again?

Comment: I would just pass another parameter with like `bool descending = false` and then have one `if(descending) objListOrder.OrderByDescending() else objListOrder.OrderBy()`.